# Cannot install apache+php with shiny app in one dockerfile

Tags: apache, docker, shiny, dockerfile, shinyapps

I have been trying to get an apache server with php to run in the same container as my shiny app container. I came across an r-apache docker image and tried to tweak for my app in my dockerfile but was unsuccessful. Below is the directory structure and the original shiny app dockerfile I used to build the shiny docker app. I will really appreciate any help.

What I really need are the commands to include in the dockerfile in order to install and run apache+php in the webapp directory.

NB: “app_image” is a combination of the docker r-base image and some additional r packages.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM app_image

# Copy the app to the image
RUN mkdir /root/webapp
COPY app/webapp /root/webapp

COPY app/Rprofile.site /usr/lib/R/etc/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 3838
EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/webapp')”]
```

**Directory Structure**

```
├── app
|   ├── webapp
|       ├── .htaccess
|       ├── server.R
|       ├── ui.R
|       └── www
|            ├── google-analytics.html
|            ├── style.css
|            └── validation.js
|   ├── Dockerfile
|   └── Rprofile.site
```